# How to resolve "TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry" in Android?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

Error description:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/google/api/client/http/AbstractInputStreamContent.class

Here is my gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.richwebs.user.hohoride"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.0.1'

}
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Comment: first tell me are you applied dexConfig?

Comment: no i am not using dexconfig

Comment: otherwise put whole gradle.build code.. so i can suggest you what you have to implement

Comment: yeah i edit my code,plz help

Answer (score 1):

there is a two way to solve this problem

1. if method refrences in your app exceeds its limit then increase heapsize like this.

> dexOptions {
>               preDexLibraries = false
>               javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
>           }

and also enable mutidexSupport like this:

```
defaultConfig {

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

dependencies {   
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

and also set name attribute in your manifest file:

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
</application>
```

2. if this will not work then you have only one option and its exclude repeated library in you gradle file. this error called "already added" and its happen when you add .jar file in lib. folder and also set gradle dependency for this.

here is my full gradle file code..

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.apple"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile project(':library')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.3.jar')
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-vector-drawable'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'animated-vector-drawable'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

i have a problem with this three module so o just exclude from all dependency, and my error gone.

Comment: bcz you are excluding from only one lib.  you should exclude from all lib like i've done. and dont pass only group. pass module also, bcz when i got this problem i refered so many link of stackoverflow. and this the best solution i found.

Comment: what is way 2? Also, did the question change? What does multidexing have to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem in different versions of imported libs

You have

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0' // wrong!
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
```

Make sure, that you always use same versions like:

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.2'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
```